# Too many re-renders when using custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

How is this happening even though I prevent it from doing this in `useEffect`, as shown below

```
//component

function LiveStreaming({ title }) {
  const [arContent, status] = useContent("story");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (arContent && arContent !== null) {
      
      console.log("arContent", arContent);
    }
  }, [arContent]);
}


//useContent

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


const localCache = {};
async function requestArContent() {
  console.log("pinging server for content");
  const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/books`);
  const json = (await res.json()) || {}; //{} so app doesn't crash if no network connection
  localCache[title] = json;
}


    export function useContent(title) {
      const [arContent, setArContent] = useState({});
      const [status, setStatus] = useState("unloaded"); //unloaded, loading, loaded
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (!title) {
          setArContent({});
        } else if (localCache[title]) {
          setArContent(localCache[title]);
        } else {
          setStatus("loading");
          requestArContent();
        }
      }, [title]);
    
      setArContent(localCache[title]);
      setStatus("loaded");
    
      return [arContent, status];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is unconditionally enqueueing state updates from the hook body, creating the render looping.

An additional issue is that `title` is undefined in `requestArContent` in the `useContent` hook definition/file, it's only defined within the `useContent` hook function body. This results in checks where `localCache[title]` isn't equal to `localCache[undefined]` set in `requestArContent` and so the final `else` is taken each time and the `status` state toggles/flips between `'loaded'` and `'loading'`.

```
const localCache = {};

async function requestArContent() {
  console.log("pinging server for content");
  const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/books`);
  const json = (await res.json()) || {}; //{} so app doesn't crash if no network connection
  localCache[title] = json; // <-- title undefined
}


export function useContent(title) {
  const [arContent, setArContent] = useState({});
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("unloaded"); //unloaded, loading, loaded

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!title) {
      setArContent({});
    } else if (localCache[title]) { // <-- title defined, localCache[title] undefined
      setArContent(localCache[title]);
    } else {
      setStatus("loading");
      requestArContent();
    }
  }, [title]);

  setArContent(localCache[title]); // <-- triggers infinite loop
  setStatus("loaded");             // <-- triggers infinite loop

  return [arContent, status];
}
```

To resolve pass `title` as an argument to `requestArContent` so the cache is updated with the `title` key. Convert the `useEffect` callback body into an `async` function such that you can `await` `requestArContent` fetching content.

```
const localCache = {};

async function requestArContent(title) { // <-- consume title arg
  console.log("pinging server for content");
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/books`);
    const json = (await res.json()) || {};
    localCache[title] = json; // <-- cache by title
  } catch(error) {
    // any error handling, logging, etc...
  }
}


export function useContent(title) {
  const [arContent, setArContent] = useState({});
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("unloaded"); //unloaded, loading, loaded

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (!title) {
        setArContent({});
      } else if (localCache[title]) {
        setArContent(localCache[title]);
      } else {
        setStatus("loading");
        await requestArContent(title); // <-- pass title as arg and wait
        setStatus("loaded");
      }
    })();
  }, [title]);

  return [arContent, status];
}
```

[image: Edit too-many-re-renders-when-using-custom-hook]

Comment: I added title but it's the error is the same.

Comment: @guest I see. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-flower-k559j

Comment: @guest I see. Please check updated answer and linked forked codesandbox.

Comment: wow, you got rid of the too many re-renders. all you did was add try/catch? how does this work?

Comment: @guest Oh, *that* try/catch was around the `fetch` since that was failing in the codesandbox iframe, it catches the failure to fetch error so the UI can actually render. The issue was the two state updates below the `useEffect` hook triggering the rerenders. Commenting them out resolved the render looping, but still had to decipher what I thought you were trying to make the code do.

Comment: yeah that's eye opening. thanks so much. It's just a simple fetch request and started the whole trail of re-rendering. i would never have thought to use try/catch as i was trying to debug and keep the code simple. but w re-rendering you never know.

Comment: and of course key was also executing the `async` inside `useEffect`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens :

- Your `LiveStreaming` function calls `useContent`
- `useContent` calls `setArContent`
- this triggers an update of `arContent` through the `useState` hook
- this triggers the `useContent` hook to run second time (after the current `useContent` and the current `render` are finished)
- this triggers a re-render (which sends you back to step one, sending you in an infinite loop)

The solution to this issue is to update the state in `useContent` only when an update is actually needed, for example like that

```
export function useContent (title) {
  const [arContent, setArContent] = useState({})
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('unloaded') //unloaded, loading, loaded

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!title) {
      setArContent({})
    } else if (localCache[title]) {
      setArContent(localCache[title])
    } else {
      setStatus('loading')
      requestArContent().then(
        () => {
          setArContent(localCache[title])
          setStatus('loaded')
        },
        err => {
          console.error(err)
        }
      )
    }
  }, [title])

  return [arContent, status]
}
```

I keep it that way to illustrate the solution to the core issue in a simpler way, but it still lacking two things in my opinion:

- The callback of useEffect needs to return an callback to "cancel" the update of the state (otherwise, you will have warnings when the component is unmounted during the async operation)
- The effect is missing dependencies which is never a good thing. Even if you don't know t the current time why (I don't), it will always bite later

Comment: I don't see what you did vs. what I did.

Answer (score 1):

enter many times to useEffect and update the status every time that is the wrong, to solve you need to use another useState to know is already executed.

```
const [executed, setExecuted] = useState(false); 
const [status, setStatus] = useState("unloaded"); 
    
      useEffect(() => {
       const getData =() =>{
        if (!title) {
          setArContent({});
        } else if (localCache[title]) {
          setArContent(localCache[title]);
        } else {
          setStatus("loading");
          requestArContent();
        }
        setExecuted(true)
       }
       if(!executed){
         getData()
       }
      }, [title]);
```